# JSF - Showing 2 sets of messages using 1 command button

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to have 2 sets of messages? I have a jsf form that is primefaces enabled, I want to display the error messages in p:messages and the success in p:growl when a single command button is hit. Is that possible?

I already tried various combination but it doesn't work like:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("myForm:messagesGrowl", message);
```

The messages always show on both the p:messages and p:growl.

My command button:

```
<p:commandButton style="float: right;" value="Send" action="#{myAction.execute()}" ajax="true" update="messages, messagesGrowl"></p:commandButton>
```

Thanks,

czetsuya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**use**

```
<p:messages autoUpdate="true" globalOnly="true" redisplay="false" />
```

**`globalOnly`**

> When true, only facesmessages with no clientIds are displayed.
>   Default is false.

**`redisplay`**

> Defines if already rendered messages should be displayed.   Default is
>   true.